# Handling a single object from collection MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a strongly typed ViewModel as shown below:

```
public class ShippingRulesViewModel
{
    //Stores a reference to the rule to be edited.
    public int Editing { get; set; }

    public List<ShippingRuleViewModel> ShippingRules { get; set; }

    public SelectList ProductFormats { get; set; } 
    public SelectList ShippingMethods { get; set; }
}
```

In the view, I am able to iterate over the ShippingRules and display each one as shown below:

```
 @foreach (var _shippingRule in Model.ShippingRules)
 {
     <tr>
         @if (_shippingRule.ID == Model.Editing) //Show rule in edit mode
         {
             using (Html.BeginForm("EditShippingRule", "Settings", FormMethod.Post))
             {
                 <td>
                     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-sm-12" value="Save"/>
                 </td>
                 <td>@Html.Raw(_shippingRule.ID)</td>
                 <td>@Html.EditorFor(sr => _shippingRule.ShipServiceLevel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm mb-md" } })</td>

... etc.
```

Now i'd like to be able to pass a single ShippingRuleViewModel back to the controller so that I can save the edit. Can this be done without having the pass the entire ShippingRulesViewModel ViewModel back? (Note the name differences).

I've tried doing this:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditShippingRule([FromBody]ShippingRuleViewModel shippingRuleViewModel)
{
```

... But I don't get anything back - Everything is null.

Have I done something wrong, or am I not able to achieve what I want?

Comment: `Form` isn't a valid child of `tr` so I'm not surprised you are having trouble. Try a different layout, like with `div`s.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes I think you are correct. After inspecting in FireBug I see: "<form method="post" action="/settings/editshippingrule/1/"></form>" with nothing inside the form element.

Comment: Why not just change `public int Editing { get; set; }` to `public ShippingRuleViewModel EditModel { get; set; }` (the loop seems unnecessary if your just creating a form for one item to be edited)

Comment: I noticed `@if (_shippingRule.ID == Model.Editing) //Show rule in edit mode`. If you are using the same view for both read only, and edit, modes, then you're doing MVC wrong. Split into a read only view and a separate edit view.